# Authorization has been denied for this request : JWT Bearer

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, owin, bearer-token

I'm using JWT to handle authentification/Authorization in my Asp.net Web Api. I've decorated my differents controller with [Authorize]. Each time I made a call, this message is Send :Authorization has been denied for this request.

Here is an example of one of my controllers :

```
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/MyParticipations")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.ActionName("XAMARIN_SelectMyEvent")]
    [Authorize]
    public HttpResponseMessage Xamarin_SelectMyEvents()
    {
        string token = Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString();
        string resultToken = Utils.Util.ValidateToken(token);
        if (resultToken == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Your session has expired");
        }
        int userId = Int32.Parse(resultToken);
        var MyEvents = db.getMyEvents(userId);
        if (MyEvents == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No Events available");
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, MyEvents);
        }
    }
```

Here is my Startup Class :

```
    public IConfiguration _Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public Startup()
    {

    }
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_Configuration[System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JWTKEY"]]))
                };
            });
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

A little problem that I didn't succeed to fix was the empty constructor in the startup Class. If I delete it, I receive an error message : "no constructor without parameters defined for this object owin".

Here is my code that generates and validate the JWT :

```
private static string Secret = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JWTKEY"];

    public static string GenerateToken(int userId)
    {
        byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(Secret);
        SymmetricSecurityKey securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);
        SecurityTokenDescriptor descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                  new Claim(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid, userId.ToString())}),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(3),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey,
            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        JwtSecurityToken token = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(descriptor);
        return handler.WriteToken(token);
    }

    public static ClaimsPrincipal GetPrincipal(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            JwtSecurityToken jwtToken = (JwtSecurityToken)tokenHandler.ReadToken(token);
            if (jwtToken == null)
                return null;
            byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(Secret);
            TokenValidationParameters parameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
            };
            SecurityToken securityToken;
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token,
                  parameters, out securityToken);
            return principal;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static string ValidateToken(string token)
    {
        string userId = null;
        ClaimsPrincipal principal = GetPrincipal(token);
        if (principal == null)
            return null;
        ClaimsIdentity identity = null;
        try
        {
            identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            return null;
        }
        Claim usernameClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid);
        userId = usernameClaim.Value;
        return userId;
    }
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with this code? I've look the others subjects but none of them gave me a solution.

Thanks for reading,

A desesperate student

Comment: Is the token generated? If yes, please share it.

Comment: Yeah the token is Generated, I will edit my post to share the code !

Comment: this is the configuration part (looks good to me). but how do you actually log in?

Comment: Yeah I guess this is the configuration part in the StartUp class, what do you mean by log in? I've a user controller that check if the user is in the Database and then a JWT is generated.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my project is an asp.net web api (not asp.Net core). I don't know if it changes something !

Comment: Authorization: Bearer generated_token. If this is the structure of authorization header, remove Bearer word before validate token. I have such type of issue in spring boot Java and resolved by removing Bearer.

Comment: @LioStudent By sharing the token, I meant the generated token itself.

Comment: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwcmltYXJ5c2lkIjoiNzMiLCJuYmYiOjE1NTA5MjgyMzgsImV4cCI6MTU1MTE4NzQzOCwiaWF0IjoxNTUwOTI4MjM4fQ.K2VhTCwO3ki5aIc4fUPXz21SRPlx4ckg7ndfwcJPItM

Comment: That's the token that I use

Comment: Is it asp net or asp net core? Because your code looks like mixed code with both frameworks

Comment: Yeah, the problem occured because it was an asp.net API and not an Asp.net Core API

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if you are doing all the following steps:

1. User provides credentials (Client-Side)
2. Credentials are approved (Server-Side)
3. Token is generated (Server-Side)
4. Token is sent to client (Server-Side)
5. Client receives the token and adds the `Authorization Header` to the
       subsequent requests' Headers with the value of "Bearer GeneratedToken" (e.g. `Authorizarion : "Bearer eyJhbGci..."`) (Client-Side)

Comment: Yeah I implemented all these steps